# Default Java EE bean type when no annotation added

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, scope, javabeans

Let's consider following two classes:

```
public class SomeInternal {
    public Integer someField;
}
```

```
public class SomeClass {
    private SomeInternal someInternal;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    public SomeClass(SomeInternal someInternal) {
        this.someInternal = someInternal;
    }
}
```

Note that `SomeInternal` class does not have any of `@Singleton`, `@Stateful` or `@Stateless` annotation.

What is the default creation method for such bean? Is it safe for field `someField` not to add `@Stateful` annotation for class `SomeInternal` (eg. two different requests for web application may modify the same field)?

I know that Spring default in such situation is `@Scope("Singleton")`, but it is not about Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided standard Java EE 6, or Java EE 7 with an explicit `bean-discovery-mode="all"` in `beans.xml`, the default scope for an `@Inject`ed bean is [`@Dependent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html). In other words, it's tied to exactly the client instance where it's being `@Inject`ed and it's not shared anywhere else.

This is a CDI scope, not an EJB scope. You appear to be mixing EJB with CDI by merely listing the EJB scopes instead of the CDI scopes [`@Dependent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html), [`@RequestScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html), [`@SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html), [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html), etc. You can at least say that it look like a `@Stateful`, but then without EJB's transaction management magic on it.

If those were `@Named` and you were referencing it in EL, then you should explicitly be using `#{someClass.someInternal.someField}` instead of `#{someInternal.someField}` to access an `@Inject`ed `@Dependent` scoped bean .